# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type in Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE

A_NAME STUDENTS_1.NAME%TYPE;
B_NAME STUDENTS_1.NAME%TYPE;
C_NAME STUDENTS_1.NAME%TYPE;
GRADE_ST STUDENTS_1.GRADE%TYPE;


CURSOR A IS SELECT NAME FROM STUDENTS_1 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(GRADE,'(A)','i');
CURSOR B IS SELECT NAME FROM STUDENTS_1 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(GRADE,'(B)','i');
CURSOR C IS SELECT NAME FROM STUDENTS_1 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(GRADE,'(C)','i');


BEGIN
GRADE_ST:= &CHOICE;


IF (GRADE_ST='A') THEN

OPEN A;
LOOP

FETCH A INTO A_NAME;

EXIT WHEN A%NOTFOUND;

INSERT INTO SCHOLARSHIP_A VALUES(A_NAME);

END LOOP;
CLOSE A;


ELSIF (GRADE_ST='B') THEN 

OPEN B;
LOOP

FETCH B INTO B_NAME;

EXIT WHEN B%NOTFOUND;

INSERT INTO SCHOLARSHIP_B VALUES(B_NAME);

END LOOP;
CLOSE B;


ELSE

OPEN C;
LOOP

FETCH C INTO C_NAME;

EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;

INSERT INTO SCHOLARSHIP_C VALUES(C_NAME);

END LOOP;

CLOSE C;



END IF;

END;

/
```

I'm making  three different scholarship tables with grades A,B,C if i user input values rather than grades i'm getting the solution but i don't want to give values as user input i want user input should be grades 
like if i input A i should get all names with grade A from the table 
but i'm ending up with this error

Comment: btw the `for r in (select x from y where z) loop` construction saves a lot of code and is generally more efficient and reliable. Or you could do the whole thing in pure SQL with `insert first when...` (multi-table insert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL*Plus or SQL Developer is substituting the `choice` variable value before the PL/SQL block is parsed, and as @mathguy suggested that may not ultimately be what you want. But here if you had `set verify on` you would able to see the code that is actually being compiled, and would see that is causing this error; this part:

```
BEGIN
GRADE_ST:= &CHOICE;
```

ends up actually being, if the user supplies the value `A`:

```
BEGIN
GRADE_ST:= A;
```

and in this scope `A` is the cursor name. So it's an invalid assignment, of a cursor to a string; hence the error you get.

Because your `choice` is a char/string you need to enclose it in quotes, so you should be doing:

```
BEGIN
GRADE_ST:= '&CHOICE';
```

You could greatly simplify what you are doing, and don't actually need PL/SQL, but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Ha! Good catch - I didn't even look at the cursor names. And only after reading this I realized I had not, in fact, answered the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a substitution variable (`&choice`) to pass in the argument. This is a SQL*Plus feature; you will need to pass in the value before your code is compiled, and then it is hard-coded in the block. Rather, what you need is a bind variable (`:choice`), or write this as a procedure that takes an `in` parameter.